# changing name of root directory in spring petclinic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want the root directory of the [spring petclinic application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/) to load at:

```
http://localhost:8080/anothername
```

instead of at:

```
http://localhost:8080/petclinic
```

Where do I make the changes in the code to cause this to happen?  I have carefully examined web.xml, mvc-core-config.xml, and other xml files but none of the changes I have made seem to change the url.

---

### ANSWER:

In addition to changing every reference I could find in the eclipse project, the missing piece was that I also had to change the following line of code in the server.xml file located within the eclipse server project:

```
<Context docBase="newappname" path="/newappname" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:newappname"/></Host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your pom.xml

work around `<path>` at

```
 <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
           <configuration>
           <server>tomcat-development-server</server>
           <port>9966</port>
           <path>/petclinic</path>
           </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Replace **petclinic** with **anothername**

Comment: Thanks for trying but that did not work.  Since this is a freely available app, are you willing to download it from the link above and tinker until you find the solution? I have changed almost everything I have found in the app to no effect.

Comment: how are you deploying in tomcat?

Comment: for now, I am doing run as...run on server from within eclipse.  I did change the part of pom.xml which indicates the name of the war file.

Comment: then you need to go to
-Project Properties- Web Project Setting
-There you would see context root as petclinic.. replace it with anothername
-rebuild
-remove the project from tomcat
-redeploy

Comment: Tried that but no effect, even after cleaning the project.  Any other ideas? Also, what do I do with these tags at start of pom.xml:  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-petclinic</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>a_new_app_name</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: I closed eclipse and restarted it, then did run as...run on server again but it still loads petclinic url.  I cannot reimport because so many changes have been made to app.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43558/discussion-between-dhamibirendra-and-codemed)

Comment: +1 for taking so much time to try to help me.  In addition to your suggestions, I had to change the server.xml file in the way I noted in an edit I just made to my original posting above.  I am marking yours as the answer, but ultimately, I had to make the change I added to my posting above in order for it actually to change the name of the root path for the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying to tomcat then the name of the context is the same as the name of the directory created under webapps (by default)